# Ordering of coordinates

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, complexity-theory

Suppose that I have `n` points

```
(x,y1),(x2,y2),.....(xn,yn)
```

my aim is  to  connect these points in such a way, that I get a spline without self intersection. My method is  to order these elements by increasing ordering of x values and, if they are equal, then compare y values. Here is my method:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;
#define N  1000
struct  Point
{
    int x;
    int y;

}point[N];
int main()
{
    int start=clock();
    int n;
    cout<<" enter  number of coordinantes " <<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cin>>point[i].x>>point[i].y;

    for(int i=1;i<=n-1;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            if(point[i].x>point[j].x)
            {
                int t=point[i].x;
                point[i].x=point[j].x;
                point[j].x=t;

            }
            if( point[i].x==point[j].x)
            {

                if(point[i].y>point[j].y)
                {
                    int s=point[i].y;
                    point[i].y=point[j].y;
                    point[j].y=s;
                }
                }


            }

    }
    int end=clock();
    cout<<"coordinantes are :"<<endl;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cout<<point[i].x<<" "<<point[i].y<<endl;
    cout<<(end-start)/(float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I entered a number of elements equal to 20, it took 102.59 milliseconds (laptop with 2.5 RAM,1.87 GH). Is my method optimal or does a better method exist?

Comment: You are writing a sort algorithm.  Yours has O(n^2) complexity; you can do much better than that.  See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about performance, I'll point out these things:

1) You are using 1000 elements - memory wastage.
   Use *point & do `malloc` for the required number of elements.

2) You are not using point[0] in your current implementation - memory wastage! ;-)

3) As others said, your sorting algorithm is not the best choice.

> when i enter number of element 20,it took 102.59 miliseconds(laptop
>   with 2.5 RAM,1.87 GH),so it is optimal way

processing 20 elements is not going to tell about the efficiency of the algorithm. The sample needs to be large enough to benchmark the program reasonably.

Answer (score 3):

The **bottleneck in your algorithm is the sort** - which is `O(n^2)`. It can be done in `O(nlogn)` - which is asymptotically much better.

You should first sort your data, using a faster sort, and then iterate on your elements invoking your second stage of the algorithm.

Also note, that **designically speaking** - *usually* it is a good practice to seperate between the parts of your program - in your case - seperate between the sort and the later traversal.

For sorting, you might want to have a look on [`std::sort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) and you might want to be familiar with [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from sorting, you could sort by your own comparison criteria.

```
boolean compare(Point A, Point B) {
   return ((A.x > B.x)||((A.x==B.x)&&(A.y>B.y)));
}
```

(apologies for syntax... My C++ is rusty)

Then you carry out the sort using a well-implemented algorithm like std::sort and this function as the comparison order.